# Firebase Cloud Functions and FCM: how to send device to device messages? (JavaScript, Swift 3)

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send device to device messages in Firebase using Cloud Functions. I've never coded in JavaScript before and am using a template from this GitHub page: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications. That's been recommended in the official documentation. However, I was trying to rewrite the code to make it fit my needs in a chat application.

What am I already doing and what should the function do?

- I'm saving the device token from FIRInstanceID to the database to make it easily retrievable from the cloud function
- I'm uploading any new message with the text, receiverID and senderUserName to a dedicated path in the database
- The cloud function observes this database path and is called every time someone uploads a new notification
- The cloud function fetches the data and sends it in a notification to the user that belongs to the receiver id after having retrieved his device token

That's my current cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/notificationsToBeProcessed').onWrite(event => {
  const data = event.data.val();
  const text = data["text"];
  const receiverID = data["receiverID"];
  const senderUserName = data["senderUserName"];

  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'Hey!',
      body: text
    }
  };

  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('/notification-tokens/{receiverID}');
  rootRef.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {

      var token = snapshot.child("{receiverID}")

      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {
        // For each message check if there was an error.
        const tokensToRemove = [];
        response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
          const error = result.error;
          if (error) {
            console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
            // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
            if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
              tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
            }
          }
        });
      });

    });

  })

})
```

And I'm getting this error when I try to deploy:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at /Users/jonas/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:18:11
```

Can someone with a little more experience in JavaScript tell me where my mistake is? Thanks!

Comment: I won't put it as an answer yet because I'm not certain this is the cause, but `var token = snapshot.child("{receiverID}")` looks for a child at the path `/notification-tokens/{receiverID}` named `{receiverID}`, brackets and all. Depending on your data structure, I assume you are looking for `snapshot.val()`.

Comment: The specific error is because you have an extra `})` on the last line. If you delete that, you'll get a different error/behavior.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh thanks! this was the mistake! :)